# php pdo insert multiple records into sql database from html input

Tags: php, pdo, insert, sqlsrv

I am finding it difficult to post data from my form into the database table;
every time tried to post into the database, i get an  error.

Its a an invoice form where i would have to enter multiple items and quantity.
Meaning, i can i have one or more items in the form.

> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\smiley\admin\estiofficer.php on line 109

**This is my form**

```
<td><input type="text" name="item[]" id="item" value="">
</td>
<td><input value ="1" type="text" onBlur="findTotal()" name="num[]" disabled>
</td>
<td><input   onBlur()="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty[]" value=""/></td>
```

**my php code**

```
$itemid = implode(',', $_POST['item']);
$qty    = implode(',', $_POST['num']);
$amount = implode(',', $_POST['qty']);
$stmt = $db->prepare('Insert INTO dbo.[DB$Estimation_Transaction] (dbo.[DB$Estimation_Transaction].item_id,dbo.[DB$Estimation_Transaction].quantity,dbo.[DB$Estimation_Transaction].amount) VALUES ' . ' (' . $itemid . ', ' . $qty . ', ' . $amount . ')');

$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {



    header("location: estimator.php?msg");
} else {
    echo "Estimation Failed";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: what does your `post` return

Comment: why is item hidden how are u gonna fill it with values?

Comment: `num` isn't an array?

Comment: There's no reason at all to post all your data as an array

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile thanks i changed it now

Comment: The last curly brace `}` tells us that this is not your full code, but if this is your full code that brace should give an error

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Its actually an invoice form, which would have a multiple inputs for item, price and quantity

Comment: @Beginner yes its the name of the input field

Comment: @Akin it returs the error ***Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\smiley\admin\estiofficer.php on line 109**

Comment: I think the point @Beginner is trying to make is that `num` is not an array because it should be `name="num[]"`. `implode` expects an array in the second argument, and currently `$_POST['num']` is a string.

Comment: @ImClarky yes you are right